# OO Javascript. Properties Issue

Tags: javascript

I come from OOP languages (Java, C# and PHP). I'm just doing some OOP in Javascript and am seriously confused on how to define a property. The code below is based on a Mozilla code example, which is the same as what I'm working with. I've also included the way I thought properties should be declared, but don't seem to work.

```
var myExtension = {

    // This is how I thought it'd be done
this.instructionServers = new Array(
    "http://server.com/json.php",
),


init: function() {  
    // The event can be DOMContentLoaded, pageshow, pagehide, load or unload.  
    if(gBrowser) {
        gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onPageLoad,false);  
    }
},  

onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {  
    var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered the event  
    var win = doc.defaultView; // win is the window for the doc  

    // Skip frames and iFrames
    if (win.frameElement) return;

    // Code removed
}
```

Comment: Truly grokking JavaScript's `this` is key to understanding the language.

Comment: @AutoSponge -- `this` always has a value. If you are in the global scope, then it is the global object (DOMWindow in web browsers)

Comment: You can't use `this` in a variable definition to refer to the object begin defined.  @divad12 has the right way to do this in a variable definition.

Comment: JavaScript is an OO language as well... just saying :)

Answer (score 3):

You should have

```
var myExtension = {
    instructionServers: ["http://server.com/json.php"],

    // ...

};
```

Alternatively, you can also assign properties in JavaScript directly, as in

```
myExtension.instructionServers = ["http://server.com/json.php"];
```

This would make `instructionServers` an array property of `myExtension`. You can then get the value of the property with

```
myExtension.instructionServers
```

or

```
myExtension['instructionServers']
```

As an aside, note that in JavaScript you can use handy array literals.

```
['hello', 3]
```

is equivalent to the more verbose and discouraged

```
new Array('hello', 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myExtension = {
        url: 'http://server.com/json.php',
        init: function() {
            alert( this.url );
        }
}

myExtension.init();
```

Technically init is a property itself, just a property of type function.  To declare a string property simply set one the same way as above.

To reference that property inside of your object use

> this

Answer (score 0):

You are using the object notation (think JSON) so there is no "=". it should be :

instructionServers:  ["http://server.com/json.php"],

Comment: Object literals should not be confused with JSON. They look similar but are two different things.

Comment: i did not mean that to be taken literally, but just the notation. Sorry, should have been a little more specific.